# How can I make an interactive drawing app in React Native?

Tags: react-native, touch, drawing, drag, interactive

how can I easily create an app like this in React Native?

[image]

As you can see on the gif I need to draw rectangles on the grid. Are there any libraries or maybe even paid commercials solutions for creating apps with advanced drawing like this shown on the gif?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: how did you proceed ?

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen this library? You might need to flicker something to meet your exact requirement

https://github.com/jgrancher/react-native-sketch

https://github.com/terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas